# GORM: List all the domain instances belonging to User (root object)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm working with grails since a while. There is something I still don't know how to implement correctly.

I have a domain class (let's say User) which contains a List which can be potentially any domain class (Item, User, etc, etc). Is there a way to make this out of the box?

At the moment I'm doing it the following way:

I have a UserLink which contains following properties:

```
class UserLink{
    User user
    String className
    Long refId
}
```

Then I have a service which loads all links for a given user and then the corresponding objects in the link, and returns them as a list.

I think this approach is not the best, and could lead to future performance problems

What do you think? Do you have better design ideas?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really any, or only a certain subset of classes? I believe you'll have some more domain classes not directly related to User.

If so, you can create a `UserAsset` class or interface with a `belongsTo=[user: User]` prop, and inherit/implement it.

Then find all domain classes implementing it, and query each with `clazz.findByUser()`, like:

```
GrailsClass[] classes = grailsApplication.getArtefacts('Domain')
GrailsClass[] userAssetClasses = 
    classes.clazz.findAll { UserAsset.class.isAssignableFrom(it) }
List<UserAsset> allUserAssets = 
    userAssetClasses.clazz*.findAllByUser(myUser).flatten()
```

**edit**: If we're talking M:M, it only changes last line, the way `userAssetClasses` are queried.

`UserAsset` will have a `hasMany=[users:User]` property.

Like:

```
List<UserAsset> allUserAssets = userAssetClasses.clazz.collect{ 
    Class domainClass ->
    it.withCriteria {
        users {
            eq('id', myUser.id)
        }
    }
}.flatten()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this would only work for a one to Many relationship. The problem is, that many users may have the same objects in their list. And yes, you are correct, not every domain object is related to the User (But many of them). 

Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: It changes very little - pls take a look at the updated idea.

Comment: I Viktor, thanks again for your effords! I ended up doing it by splitting the class hierarchy. Turned out to be much more elegant in code. The other solutions would have made the code tu complex to understand and mantain. Thanks