# Polymorphic belongsTo in many to many mapping in grails?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

So i know this is possible using a superclass, however, this is very limiting in flexibility. So my question is then, can i use an interface? Something ala.

```
interface Taggable {
  /*Adds tag(s) and returns a list of currently set tags*/
  List<String> addTags(String ... tag)
  /*Removes tag(s) and returns a list of currently set tags*/
  List<String> removeTags(String ... tag)
}

class User implements Taggable {
  String username
  static hasMany = [tags:Tag]
}

class Tag {
  String name

  static hasMany = [references:Taggable]
  static belongsTo = Taggable

  static constraints = {
    name(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
  }
}
```

Im interested in a reference back to the object who has the following tag. This object however can't extend a concrete class. Thats why im wondering if this can be done with an interface instead.

**So, can it be done?**

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate can map an interface - [see example](http://jpaobjects.sourceforge.net/m2-site/main/documentation/docbkx/html/user-guide/ch04s09.html). I doubt if Grails supports this in by-convention mapping - but you can try using the mapping [annotations](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html#15.2%20Mapping%20with%20Hibernate%20Annotations) from example above, or XML config.

**edit**: answering a comment question:

On a database level, you have to have a `Taggable` table for `Tag.References` to reference with a foreign key.

1. Discriminator will NOT defeat polymorphism, if it's added automatically - for instance, in table-per-hierarchy mapping, Hibernate/Gorm adds a `class` field in order to find out a concrete class when reading object from db.
2. If you map your `Taggable`s to two tables - `Taggable` part to `Taggable` and everything else to specific table, referenced 1:1 - all the discriminator work should be done for you by Hibernate.

*BTW `class` field is pretty long - it contains fully qualified class name*.

**edit 2**:
Either way, it's getting pretty complex, and I'd personally go with the approach I suggested [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5912170/207791):

- dynamically query all the classes with Taggable interface for `hasMany=[tags:Tag]` property;
- or, less preferable - to have a hand-crafted child table and a discriminator.

Comment: Yes you are probably right, i don't think i can use grails gorm mapping to do this. However, in your example it seems that i need to add discriminators to the annotations with references to the speicific classes, and this does somewhat defeat the purpose of polymorphism. And also degrades the flexibility of the `Tag` implementation... **So the question becomes, can one have an any mapping without discriminators that needs class references in code?**

Comment: XML is always an option tho, that way we won't have a reference to implementation classes in the source code... but who likes XML nowadays?

Comment: Sorry for not coming up with a snippet - this is going to take too long. Just a raw idea to try. Annotations still might work, and people do use XML - for the ability to have different mapping for different DBMSes. Just pick what's better for specific case.

Comment: A side question: you say that the `class` field is very long, which im taking to be a negative thing? does the class field itself have a performance penalty? is this the reason why three letter discriminators are used? isn't it possible to index the class field or optimize it in any way? (join table?)

Comment: I just thought of another possible solution. Maybe with the power of groovy one could add database mapping programmatically? pseudocode: find all domain classes implementing Taggable. add a @MetaValue for each class on the `Tag` class. (oh and btw, sorry for picking your brain to this extent :))

Comment: Just as a matter of record size - if `Tag` record is several bytes long small, and you have lots of - `class` field will make it ~40 bytes longer. Depends on your DB requirements. Though, it's guaranteed to be unique :) I believe they use specified discriminator in order to reduce record size, or to adopt legacy "polymorphic table-per-hierarchy" databases.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, the bet is worth it :) Some do more picking for just 25 rep %)) This post has something about manipulating mappings in runtime, though not sure how Grails would react: http://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields

Comment: I updated my answer to some previous question - I believe it's about the same thing. It's going to be more visible convention then modifying domain class mapping on the fly, and querying is pretty brief.