# How to implement delegation with metaClass and invokeMethod?

Tags: grails, groovy

im trying to create a tagging solution which is a bit flexible. I have previously thought about solving it like this: [Polymorphic belongsTo in many to many mapping in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926567/polymorphic-belongsto-in-many-to-many-mapping-in-grails) . But as this doesn't seem to bear any fruit so I wen't ahead in another direction.

What im trying to do now is to detect wheter a domain class has a `hasMany` reference to the `Tag` class. If it does, then i try to assign method delegation to the `taggableService`.

All the following code is trying to do is to find the specified method and invoke it on the current object. However if it doesn't find it then try to invoke it on the delegate object instead. And if all fails, throw a MissingMethodException.

```
for(GrailsClass c in grailsApplication.getDomainClasses()){
    Map hasMany = c.getPropertyValue('hasMany')

    //continue of has a many mapping with Tag class as its endpoint
    if(hasMany && hasMany.containsValue(Tag)){

        //replace invokeMethod with a delegate strategy
        c.clazz.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
            def metaMethod = c.clazz.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name,args)
            if(metaMethod){
                return metaMethod.invoke(delegate,args);
            }

            metaMethod = taggableService.class.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
            if(metaMethod){
                return metaMethod.invoke(taggableService,args);
            }
            throw new MissingMethodException(name,delegate.class,args)
        }
    }
}
```

This however doesn't seem to have the desired effect. I've have gone a bit lost in groovyland, can anyone help me?

Comment: have you looked at the taggable plugin http://www.grails.org/plugin/taggable

Comment: yes i have, but I have decided to create my own, as i don't like every aspect of the plugin's design.

Comment: Turns out it was just the test framework who didn't handle the bootstrap correctly. if i tested it in a controller class instead. it worked fine... :(

Comment: As another tips, to anyone else trying to do the same. You can use methodMissing/missingMethod (dont remeber wich one it is) instead of invokeMethod, so if the method is missing you just pass it on to the delegate. much less code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just the test framework who didn't handle the bootstrap correctly. if i tested it in a controller class instead. it worked fine... :(